# Psycopg2 Full Outer Join with Python 2.6

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.6, psycopg2

I am brand new to using psycopg2 to interact with a postgreSQL database. I am attempting to do a full outer join and cannot find any documentation to help me with the command. Here is what I am attempting in Python 2.6:

```
cursor.execute("""
SELECT spl.id,
   spl.index,
   spl.d_id,
   spl.p_id,
   spl.pattern,
   spe.id,
   spe.index,
   spe.d_id,
   spe.p_id,       
FROM s_phrase_label spl
FULL OUTER JOIN s_pattern_extraction spe
ON spl.thread.id = spe.id
   AND spl.d_id = spe.d_id,
   AND spl.index = spe.index
""")
```

but I keep getting errors. Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: The error is

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "AND"
LINE 14:                        AND spl.index = spe.index
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma:

```
spl.d_id,
   spl.p_id,
   spl.pattern  //Right here
spe.id,
```

Comment: @ztoolson Since I don't have your schema available, could it also be that you mean to type `spl.thread_id` instead of `spl.thread.id`?

Comment: @ztoolson Did that fix the issue or are you seeing more problems? I would suggest taking the query itself and trying to run it in a DB console/app. There's several good tools Squirrel, Toad, or PGAdmin to name a few.

Answer (score 1):

You should not place a comma in the middle of a logical expression used in a `WHERE` clause:

```
...
AND spl.d_id = spe.d_id, -- This is an error.
AND spl.index = spe.index
...
```

Also, this has nothing to do with psycopg: it is an SQL syntax error.